# Set data in React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, redux-reducers

This is my code.

```
const initialNoticeState = {
    id: props,
    title       : '',
    description : '',
    image : '',
    updated_by  : user.firstName+' '+user.lastName,
    priority    : ''
  };
  const [currentNotice, setCurrentNotice] = useState(initialNoticeState);
  const notice = useSelector(state => state.notices.currentNotice)
  const [noticeImage, setNoticeImage] = useState("");
  const [imgData, setImgData] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(noticeActions.getById(props.id))
  }, [props.id]);
```

I want to `setCurrentNotice` from `notice` value, just after `dispatch` finishes.

Here is the data of `notice`:

[image]

Comment: @ Ramesh Reddy  No.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to setCurrentNotice from notice value, just after dispatch
> finishes.

useEffect can be used to execute functions when variable is changed.

```
  useEffect(() => {
   setCurrentNotice(notice)
  }, [notice]); //notice is the dependency
```

Comment: It shows error as it find notice and continues repeatedly. 

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: if u use useEffect with notice as dependency, you cannot use useEffect with currentNotice as dependency and dispatch again.. It will cause a loop.

Comment: @usafder notice !== currentNotice

Answer (score 0):

Just Like that

```
setCurrentNotice({your current notice data})
```

Comment: in useeffect() first it dispatch to get data and I wanted to know how to set this data to currentNotice after dispatching. like useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(noticeActions.getById(props.id));
setCurrentNotice(notice);
  }, [props.id]);

it won't work for first time. it worked after 2nd click.

Comment: I do not understand, to set is just like that on click about some button make onclick event
and also set the notice.